# pandas dataframe to parquet file conversion

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-s3, parquet

I am trying to move a csv file from s3 bucket to another by converting it to txt file and I am getting all sorts of delimiter issues. So i decided to convert the csv to parquet files , but i am not sure if I am doing it right.
Is this the right way to convert to a parquet file.
We have a another ETL (glue crawler) that picks up these parquet files and populates them to redshift. I can see the parquet file in the s3 bucket,but not in the redshift database. So wondering if the file is converted to parquet correctly.

```
bucket = 'source bucket'
file = 'file path'
    
    
    obj = client.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file)
    initial_df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
    
    
    file = 'file.parquet'
    bucketdest = 'destinationbucketname'
    buf = BytesIO()
    initial_df.to_parquet(buf, index=False)
    s3_file = 'path'+file
    print(s3_file)
    buf.seek(0)
    s3 = session2.resource('s3')
    s3.Object(bucketdest, s3_file).put(Body=buf.getvalue())
    print('loaded')
```

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to save the Pandas DF to parquet format, you need run the below command

```
df.to_parquet('C:\\Desktop\myfile.parquet')
```

You may get the below error.

ImportError: Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'.
pyarrow or fastparquet is required for parquet support

install pyarrow or fastparquet libraries to solve the issue

```
pip install pyarrow
pip install fastparquet
```